# Can System.Text.Json be used to decode and parse an encoded JSON string?

Tags: json, .net-core

I have some incoming text that is encoded JSON.

`{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\"}`

When I try to parse that with `JsonDocument.Parse(text)` I get an error complaining about the \ character.

I tried...

```cs
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
   Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};

var obj = JsonDocument.Parse(text, options);
```

...but that did not help.

I'm missing a step here. I was thinking about just stripping out the \ first, but if a decoder is available that will be preferable.

Is there an option or method built into the System.Text.Json namespace that I can use to prepare that string before I attempt to parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need any options

```
    var json="{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\"}";

    var obj = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
```

result

```
{
  "field1": "value1",
  "field2": "value2"
}
```

or if you need to deserialize

```
Data data= System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Data>(json);

public partial class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("field1")]
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("field2")]
    public string Field2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @serge, Your answer provided the clue I needed. The strings I was using did not have the leading and trailing double quote marks. After I added those to match your example, it works fine.